# ORA-22288 when trying to read BLOB from Windows directory

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to read BLOB from Windows directory located on the Oracle 11g DB server:

```
create or replace directory BLOB_DIR as 'C:\data\images';

grant read, write on directory BLOB_DIR to public;

set serveroutput on;

declare
    l_bfile  BFILE;
begin
    l_bfile := BFILENAME('BLOB_DIR', 'blob.jpg');
    DBMS_LOB.fileopen(l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);
    DBMS_LOB.fileclose(l_bfile);
end;
/
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 744
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

I checked the directory and file exist and all the permissions are given to Everyone.

What am I doing wrong? How to get more specific error message?

Comment: I think oracle doesn't translate relative path, you might want to try using UNC path.

Comment: You the directory has to exist in the server, not on your client?

Comment: @OldProgrammer, the directory is on the server

Comment: @T.Peter, I tried to share the folder and create the directory using UNC path; the same error

Comment: @SergeIroshnikov mind pasting the UNC path you use?

Comment: @T.Peter, the path was like '\\SERGEIR\IMAGES'.
I worked with relative paths when extracted blobs into files:

CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY BLOBS AS 'C:\TEMP\BLOBS';

v_output := utl_file.fopen('BLOBS', vfilename,'wb', 32760);

However, DBMS_LOB needs some tricks to open files.